# Unable to connect to xmpp account with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, xmpp

I am trying to connect to a IM account (WebEx connect - Protocol: Jabber/xmpp) with Thunderbird 15 but it fails to connect. It doesn't throw any error just says **"Not Connected"**.

Pidgin works perfectly with the same setting what I provided in Thunderbird 15.

So the question is

1. Will Thunderbird chat account(xmpp) support libnss3
2. Do I debug and collect info, when Thunderbird tries to connect to a chat account?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [link](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/xmpp_connection_works_with_pidgin_fails_with_thunderbird) shared by [unor](https://askubuntu.com/users/82665/unor) helped me to fix this issue.

The IM account was unable to connect due to certificate issue. Though I had a valid certificate the app wasn't able to verify the certificate.

Here is the detailed steps on how to fix the issue.

### Get the proper certificates

1. Get the **certificate** (If you don't have one) from pidgin account.

   - open **Tools** -> **Certificates**
   - select the appropriate hostname and click "**Save**" (file: certificate.pem)
2. Open Thunderbird -> Edit -> Preference -> Advanced

   - choose **Certificates** tab -> View Certificates
   - Select **Servers** and Click Import to add the download "Certificate.pem" and save it.

or

1. Use this link https://kingant.net/check_xmpp_dns/ to get proper server details.

   - open the link and enter "yourdomain.com" to fetch the server details
     [image]
   - Copy the Target value in "Client records for yourdomain.com". In this case, it is **c2s.webex.com.webexconnect.com**
2. Open Thunderbird -> Edit -> Preference -> Advanced

   - choose **Certificates** tab -> View Certificates
   - Select **Servers**
   - Click on "Add Exception..."
   - Enter the copied text under "**Server Location:**" with **:5222** at the end (Replace https:// with  c2s.webex.com.webexconnect.com:5222)
   - Click on "Get Certificate" and remember to tick "Permanently Store this exception" and save the setting by clicking on "Confirm Security Exception"

### Adding XMPP account

1. Open Thunderbird -> Edit -> Account Settings
2. Add Chat Account

   - select xmpp
   - **username**: name@domain.com
   - **password**: **.......**
   - **Resource**: Doesn't really matter
   - **Server**: im.domain.com or the text grabbed from the URL(c2s.webex.com.webexconnect.com)
   - **Port** : 5222

Now we are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the certificate exception did seem work from Tbird to Openfire -- I then had a new error "Not authorized (Did you enter the wrong password?)" so still stuck.

I then change the username (from format "abc" to "abc@server") and that corrected the issue.  Some clients want username, some want user@server.

My 2 cents worth to help those that found this issue.